# Definition not working with standalone

Tags: beamer, standalone

I have a definition to highlight text in beamer that I obtained from some post here. It works fine when I use `beamer` class, but complains about the definition when I use `standalone` class. This is in an externally defined file that I `\input` and I need other definitions in that file content when I generate some PDF figures using the standalone class. So, it would be helpful if I can resolve this. Anyone has ideas why the definition fails with the `standalone` class? Here is a MWE that works:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
%---This is for highlighting text on overlays ----
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\renewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\SoulColor{%
    \let\set@color\beamerorig@set@color
    \let\reset@color\beamerorig@reset@color}
\makeatother
\SoulColor

\begin{document}
    \frame{\hl{Test}
    }
    
\end{document}
```

But as soon as I convert `beamer` to `standalone`, it gives me the error:

```
line 7: Command < undefined. \renewcommand<
line 7: Missing control sequence inserted. \renewcommand<>
line 7: Argument of \SOUL@n has an extra }. \renewcommand<>{\hl}
line 7: Paragraph ended before \SOUL@n was complete. \renewcommand<>{\hl}
line 7: Missing \begin{document}. \renewcommand<>{\hl}[
line 7: Undefined control sequence. \renewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only
line 7: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. \renewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#
line 7: Undefined control sequence. ...ewcommand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal
line 7: Argument of \SOUL@n has an extra }. ...mand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}
line 7: Paragraph ended before \SOUL@n was complete. ...mand<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}
line 7: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode. ...d<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}}{#
line 7: Missing \begin{document}. ...<>{\hl}[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal{\hl}}{#1
line 15: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
line 17: Undefined control sequence. }
line 19: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
line 19: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
line 19: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
line 19: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
line 19: Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
: Unused global option(s): [xcolor].
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since the `<>` syntax from beamer is no-standard, it is obvious it will not worth with standalone. What exactly is your end goal here?

Comment: How are you “converting to `standalone`”?

Comment: @daleif My end goal is to be able to simply \input the file that contains all these common definitions that I use across presentations. I now use that file in creating (selectively) pdf versions of some of the figures in various presentations to be used in a book (I don't want to send the publisher Tikz files). For that I have a master file using the standalone class that generates pdf files for figure files (in Tikz) that I specify. I am trying to see if I can avoid maintaining two separate definition files -- one for beamer class and one for standalone.

Comment: @egreg What I meant is that I change "beamer" class spec to "standalone" in the \documentclass statement.

Comment: well you can't use commands which use beamer specials like `<>`, `\only`, `\beamerorig@set@color` and `\beameroriginal` outside beamer. So either change the commands or accept that you need two versions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That, of course, makes sense. I'll use two versions.

Comment: Please add an example of your standalone document. If you use the beamerarticle package, you could have separate definition based on the mode.